# NetCore API Impersonate

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, impersonation

I have a Web and an API NetCore Application running in a machine that I have access by VPN.

There, in IIS, I've configured both applications in IIS: The Web and the API. They are running well.

At the API, I've tryied to open the file from a network path:
\10.50.20.24\g$\Buffer\821003\003\22\34\821003003223428.WAV

In my code, when I try to verify if the file exists, using System.IO.File, to after move it, I received a message saying that the file doesn't exists.

"file was not found"

But the file exists, and the file is there when I try to access it from Windows Explorer.

In the IIS, I've configured the same user to run the application, in the Identity of the application pool.

I've tried lots of things to try to access the file, unsuccessfully.

Do you think this is related to Impersonation? How could I implement Impersonation in Asp.Net Core API 3.1 ?

Comment: That's an administrative share, not just any network path. Only administrators can use them. Don't do that. Create a proper file share on that server and use it, eg `\\thatserver\Buffer\....`. With file shares you can use specific permissions to control who can read, write etc. You can also control *offline caching*, versioning and a ton of other advanced features

Comment: Actually , the path exists to provide resources (files) for two systems read files from there. The issue is how to access from a NetCore Application. You mean "Only administrators" because of $ on the path?

Comment: Yes. Don't use `c$`. Use a proper file share you can control. Add the appropriate permissions to that share to allow the web site account to access the path. No need to impersonate anyone. If you use a *local* account, it will appear as the computer's account to other machines on the network (ie `somedomain\somemachine$`. You could add that account to the share, or you could create a domain account for the web site.

Comment: The problem is that the environment is not under our control, is a environment created by the customer, and all the system use to access in this way, except by the fact that we are running our app in other network of the folder shared. Thanks to help me.

Comment: Going even farther, you could use [managed or virtual service accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/service-accounts). One such example is the [Application Pool Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) in IIS. The OS itself manages the account password in that case

Comment: Yes, and this is the issue. The user which is running API, in IIS, doesn't have permission to copy files from this network folder, the result, as posted at the post, is "file was not found"